# Contador de tempo regressivo

Tags: c++, jogos, runtime

Estou a criar um mini-jogo com várias perguntas e quero que tenha tempo,ou seja, quero um contador que vá de **x** até **zero**. O contador só precisa de ter segundos e minutos. Alguém sabe de alguma função em **C++** ou alguma "gambiarra" para obter uma contagem regressiva?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O melhor jeito para se fazer um contador em jogos é usando *Threads*, pois assim será possível contar o tempo sem a interferência das *Frames* do jogo (*FPS*).

```
void time_decrement(void *game_config){
    GameConfig *gc = (GameConfig*) game_config;

    while(gc->time > 0){
        sleep(1);
        gc->time--;
    }

    gc->game_loop = false;
}
```

main:

```
//...
pthread_create(&line,NULL,time_decrement,(void *) g_config);
//...
```

`GameConfig` representa um `struct` ou `classe` que possua as configurações do jogo, (tempo, pause, fim de jogo, etc). É um meio opcional, mas do meu ponto de vista, é melhor que deixar em variáveis separadas.

Nesse exemplo a *Thread* encerrará o jogo assim que o contador chegar a **0**.

Comment: Obrigadão! Ajudou d+!